# Как убрать маркеры у путевых точек? (яндекс map api)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

У меня есть 2 путевые точки и некоторое количество транзитных точек. Эти точки формируют маршрут. Путевые точки являются начальной и конечной. Они имеют маркеры со значение "A" и "B". Вот как мне убрать эти маркеры?

---

Вот ссылка на [codepen](https://codepen.io/zilermand/pen/MGVEwb) и код:

```
function init () {

  var multiRoute = [];

  function createMultiRoute(routeData, viaData, color) {
    multiRoute.push( new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
        referencePoints: routeData,
        params: viaData
      }, {
        editorDrawOver: false,
        wayPointDraggable: true,
        viaPointDraggable: true,
        routeStrokeColor: "000088",
        routeActiveStrokeColor: color,
        pinIconFillColor: color,
        boundsAutoApply: true,
        zoomMargin: 30
    }));
  }

  // Создаем карту с добавленными на нее кнопками.
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [55.750625, 37.626],
    zoom: 14
  });

  createMultiRoute([
        [60.014919, 30.649850],
        [60.014958, 30.648536],
        [60.017671, 30.646447],
        [60.019146, 30.645540],
        [60.024197, 30.645711],
        [60.025782, 30.644554],
        [60.028975, 30.640299],
        [60.027754, 30.630244],
        [60.024331, 30.631359],
        [60.023627, 30.637576],
        [60.023723, 30.638850],
        [60.024200, 30.645713]
      ], {
      viaIndexes: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
      }, "ff0000");

    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute[0]);

}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

---

```css
#map {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #000;
}
```

---

```html
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно скрыть пин, используя те же префиксы, которыми вы настраиваете внешний вид:

```
wayPointVisible: false
```

Правда в этом случае точка станет неактивной и её нельзя будет драгать и потеряет смысл запись `wayPointDraggable: true`.

Если драг точки важен, то вы можете сделать свой менее заметный пин.